# Cannot connect to .net container started by docker compose

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I started a .net service with a mysql database and all containers are running

```
109eeaf260e8        authentication_service:latest   "dotnet out/Authenti…"   9 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:5003->80/tcp     authenticationservice_authentication_service_1
5da4ab86b093        mysql:8.0.3                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:3305->3306/tcp   authenticationservice_authentication_service_d
```

Now I send a HTTP request by postman to `http://192.168.0.4:5003/api/authentication/5` I tried with `:5000`, `:80`or `authentification_serivce:PORT` as well. But always I receive a timeout or a not found.

When I start the same by IDE and call `http://localhost:5000/api/authentication/5` I receive the expected value.

I tried to work with `EXPOSE 80` in my `Dockerfile` but without success.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  overlay:
services:
  authentication_service:
    image: authentication_service:latest
    depends_on:
      - "authentication_service_db"
      - "adminer"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - authentication_service_db
    ports:
      - 5003:80
    networks:
      - overlay
  authentication_service_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.3
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: authenticationdb
    ports:
      - 3305:3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data-authentication:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - overlay
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - overlay
```

My container is living (and listening)

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

So I'm confused. How can I connect to the .net app in my service? It seems that my port mapping is wrong or I forgot a basic configuration in my docker-compose or in .net?

(If you need some more configs from project or Dockerfile please leave a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a `authentication_service`with port mapping

```
ports:
      - 5003:80
```

in your docker-compose.yml. This means that requests on port 5003 on your docker host will be forwarded to port 80 of your authentication_service-container.

So (if the container of the authentication_service is really listening on port 80) the URL you have to fire against on your docker host is:

`http://localhost:5003/api/authentication/5`